# Is there a way to set the window's scroll position without using scroll() or scrollTo()?

Tags: javascript, safari, scroll, onkeydown

...the reason I ask is that Safari has a bug in its implementation of scroll() that is breaking my UI.

Imagine a page:

```
<body>
    <div id="huge" style="width: 4000px; height: 4000px;"></div>
</body>
```

...so that you get both horizontal and vertical scrollbars. Now, normally when you press the scrollbar, the page scrolls (vertically). For the purposes of our fancy UI we don't want that to happen, so we squash the keyDown event:

```
window.onkeydown = function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 32)
    {
        return false;
    }
};
```

This works great...unless we decide that instead of preventing scrolling altogether, we want our own, custom scrolling behavior:

```
window.onkeydown = function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 32)
    {
        window.scroll(foo, bar); // Causes odd behavior in Safari
        return false;
    }
};
```

In other browsers (Chrome, Firefox), this will instantaneously move the window's scroll position to the desired coordinates. But in Safari this causes the window to *animate* to the desired scroll position, similar to the scrolling animation that takes place if you press the space bar.

Note that if you trigger this scroll off of any key OTHER than the space bar, the animation does not take place; the window scrolls instantly as in other browsers.

If you happen to be scrolling, say, 1000 pixels or more, then the animated scroll can induce some serious discomfort.

I'm scratching my head trying to find a way around this. I suspect that there isn't one, but I'm hoping some God of Javascript here can suggest something. I'd really like to be able to use the space bar for this command.

Comment: Have you considered setting the Y offset directly, rather than asking window.scroll to do it for you? I handle scrolling in Safari that way, and it works great. I agree that it's not a pristine solution.

Comment: @Pete I'm not sure what you mean. As in manually adjusting the Y-position of my #huge div? Or something else?

Comment: huge.style.top = target_scroll_to.toString() + 'px';

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use `document.documentElement.scrollTop = ...` (and `document.body` in some browsers).

Answer (score 2):

If you know where in the document you want to scroll to then you can simply use named anchors. Setting `document.location` to the anchor (e.g. `#top`, `#div50` or whatever) should be *very* reliable.

Comment: Sadly I need to use pixel coordinates, but that's a wonderful idea! I suppose I could always create a temporary, absolutely-positioned anchor and then immediately scroll to it...